# substr integer in postgres yields different result

Tags: postgresql, integer, substr

Why does substr() works differently for integer in Postgres 9.3

```
select substr(cast ( 020020 as text ),3) 
outputs 020

it is ignoring the 3rd char
```

However

```
select substr('020020',3, 6)
outputs 0020

it includes the 3rd char ( which is correct )
```

Why does it happen ? and how can I get same results in both cases regardless of the type checking

Comment: Try this: `select substr(cast ( 20020 as text ),3)`

Comment: oh make sense dint think of that .. thanks :)